# ES6 Generators not working correctly when send arguments by next()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Im not understand the idea, wrong was happened in this code:

[image: Image Code]

Output always undefined for first item...(Also if I set another yieldData5.next(...) after last line of code, it will be print on console

(undefined

bye : taher

undefined)

thanks,

Comment: Well, you are not passing anything to the function, so `i` is `undefined` and therefore  `yield i;` is equivalent to `yield undefined;`. You are explicitly yielding `undefined` from the function, and that's what you see. Not sure what else you would expect?

Comment: how I can fix this issue, or other meaining how I can passing obj and used by yield ^^, Thanks

Comment: If your question is how to reference the value passed to the first call of `.next`, the answer is unfortunately: You can't. [This is being addressed in the next version of ECMAScript](https://github.com/allenwb/ESideas/blob/master/Generator%20metaproperty.md).

Answer (score 2):

> Output always undefined for first item

You are not passing anything to the function, so `i` is `undefined` and therefore `yield i;` is equivalent to `yield undefined;`. You are explicitly yielding `undefined` from the function, and that's what you see.

---

If your question is how to reference the value passed to the first call of `.next`, the answer is unfortunately: You can't.

[This is being addressed in the next version of ECMAScript](https://github.com/allenwb/ESideas/blob/master/Generator%20metaproperty.md).

Comment: yes, thats what I need, Then If I need to get specific index, Im must use another idea, like " for of ", But I think its so bad to iteration items to find or Get item needed ... is there any Idea you know can be used ? thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let yieldData5 = collection_name5({index: 0, masg: 'Hi');
console.log(collection_name5.next({index: 2, masg: 'bye').value);
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants to achieve.